# How to change Chinese reference format in biblatex package?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting

First I want to give a minimal working sample and my `bib` file.

**The working sample is**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{ctexbook} 
%%%添加参考文献%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = caspervector, utf8, 
sorting = ecnty,seconds=true,maxnames = 9999,
ugly]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{liuref.bib}
\begin{document}

\supercite{Aoml1970},\parencite{Aecl1971},\parencite{Lyym1995}三种；


\printbibliography[title = {文献}, heading = bibintoc]  \nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

**My `liuref.bib`file is**

```
@incollection{Aoml1970,
  title={Advice on modal logic},
  author={D. Scott},
  booktitle={Philosophical Problems in Logic: Some Recent Developments},
  editor={K. Lambert},
  pages={143--173},
  year={1970},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@phdthesis{Aecl1971,
    title    = {An Essay in Classical Modal Logic},
    school   = {Stanford University},
    author   = {K. Segerberg},
    year     = {1971},
    type     = {{PhD} dissertation},
    note={\url{http://lpcs.math.msu.su/~zolin/ml/pdf/Segerberg_Essay_1971.pdf}},
}

@article{Lyym1995,
  title={方法论研究},
  author={神州 and 华夏 and 北极 and 南京},
  year={1995},
  journal={辽阔大江},
  volume={5},
  pages={52-56},
  language={chinese}
}

@inproceedings{talbot97,
author = {Talbot, Nicola and Cawley, Gavin’},
title = {A fast index assignment algorithm for robust vector quantisation of image data},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the I.E.E.E. International Conference on Image Processing},
address = {Santa Barbara, California, USA},
year = {1997},
}

@article{molodtsov1999soft,
  title={Soft set theory—first results},
  author={Molodtsov, Dmitriy},
  journal={Computers \& Mathematics with Applications},
  volume={37},
  number={4-5},
  pages={19--31},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

I use `xelatex+biber+xelatex+xelatex` to compile and get the following result:

[image]

My **GOAL** is

> 1. I want to make all the titles be the default font for (only) English references.
> 2. I want to add in all the titles (including titles for **book, booklet,inbook, proceedings, in proceedings=conference, collection, newspaper, article, mastersthesis, phdthesis, techreport, unpublished**; not including other kinds of titles) a 《》for all the (only) Chinese references.
> 3. I don't want to change the other formats for all the references.

The following figure are the formats for English and Chinese references, which I want. *I can only get either for English ones or Chinese ones, but can't get them at the same time*.

[image]

***AND***

[image]

Who can help me? Any help would be appreciated and welcome!

Comment: Your question is not really clear enough to properly answer. You say you want the default font for English references. What is this default? You can't mean the default from the `caspervector` style, since your second image differs considerably from what your MWE gives. It might help if you set your MWE to give the English output you want, then tell us the required changes needed for Chinese.

Comment: @David Purton Thanks very much! But I have get what I want by my self.

Answer (score 4):

The definitions you need to modify are found in `biblatex-caspervector-utf8.def` and `caspervector.bbx`.

This seems to more or less match what you want (see comments for description):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{ctexbook} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Aoml1970,
  title     = {Advice on modal logic},
  author    = {D. Scott},
  booktitle = {Philosophical Problems in Logic: Some Recent Developments},
  editor    = {K. Lambert},
  pages     = {143--173},
  year      = {1970},
  publisher = {Springer}
}
@phdthesis{Aecl1971,
  title  = {An Essay in Classical Modal Logic},
  school = {Stanford University},
  author = {K. Segerberg},
  year   = {1971},
  type   = {{PhD} dissertation},
  note   = {\url{http://lpcs.math.msu.su/~zolin/ml/pdf/Segerberg_Essay_1971.pdf}},
}
@article{Lyym1995,
  title    = {方法论研究},
  author   = {神州 and 华夏 and 北极 and 南京},
  year     = {1995},
  journal  = {辽阔大江},
  volume   = {5},
  pages    = {52-56},
  language = {chinese},
}
@inproceedings{talbot97,
  author    = {Talbot, Nicola and Cawley, Gavin’},
  title     = {A fast index assignment algorithm for robust vector quantisation of image data},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the I.E.E.E. International Conference on Image Processing},
  address   = {Santa Barbara, California, USA},
  year      = {1997},
}
@article{molodtsov1999soft,
  title     = {Soft set theory—first results},
  author    = {Molodtsov, Dmitriy},
  journal   = {Computers \& Mathematics with Applications},
  volume    = {37},
  number    = {4-5},
  pages     = {19--31},
  year      = {1999},
  publisher = {Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=caspervector,utf8,sorting=ecnty,seconds=true,maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\makeatletter
% use English period for Chinese
\renewcommand*\bbx@cnperiod{\addperiod\space}
% Use Chinese opening double quote
\renewcommand*\bbx@cnldquot{《}
% Use Chinese closing double quote
\renewcommand*\bbx@cnrdquot{》}
% Don't use quotes for English
\renewcommand*{\bbx@mybibquote}[1]%
  {\bbx@cepunct{\bbx@cnldquot{#1}\bbx@cnrdquot}{#1}}
% Quote Chinese titles and emphasise English titles
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\bbx@mybibquote{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{\bbx@mybibquote{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{\bbx@mybibquote{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{\bbx@mybibquote{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
% Don't emphasise English titles for article, etc.
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, inproceedings, incollection, article]{title}{%
  \bbx@mybibquote{#1}}
% Don't bold volume
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{#1}
% Don't emphasise year
\DeclareFieldFormat*{year}{#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title = {文献}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of English and Chinese references in my file, so your method doesn't work for very well. Thank you very much although it's not what I finally want.

Comment: Well, it only deals with thee information you have in the question. But you should be able to go make any other changes you need by looking through the files I mentioned. Otherwise ask new questions with specific requests.

Comment: By the way what's your real name? I'd like to show thanks to people who help me a lot on latex when writing my book. Also, how do you read your surname?